# How to resolve UnhandledException at [UnityAppController(Rendering) repaintDisplayLink]

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, exception, crash

This crash is by far topping our crash logs, and we just can't figure out what is causing it. So I turn to you guys for help.

My research in this topic hints that a possible cause is when we're either trying to display an ad at a different orientation than the game is using, or if we resume the app in another orientation than it had when it was minimized. It also looks like this was a thing back in 2016 and was resolved in Unity 5.6.0. This does not help very much though, since we're currently using Unity 2018.4.6f1.

We are unable to reproduce this crash ourselves, but we're seeing tons of crashes like this on Firebase Crashlytics. So that's all we have to go on.

Here's some info that could be relevant:
**Unity:** 2018.4.6f1
**Affected devices:** iphone, ipad
**Affected OS:** iOS 9 - iOS 13
**Xcode version:** 11.1

Unity player settings configuration:
**Default orientation:** Auto rotation
**Use Animated Autorotation:** true
**Allowed Orientations for Auto Rotation:** Landscape Right, Landscape Left

A typical crash log looks like this:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  GameApp            0x100533da8 CrashedCheckBelowForHintsWhy + 118 (CrashReporter.mm:118)
1  GameApp            0x102c9563c void firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::DeleteT<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(void*) + 27033940
2  GameApp            0x1005fe8bc RuntimeInvoker_TrueVoid_tDB81A15FA2AB53E2401A76B745D215397B29F783_RuntimeObject_RuntimeObject(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) + 22071 (Il2CppInvokerTable.cpp:22071)
3  GameApp            0x10126b4b8 il2cpp::vm::Runtime::Invoke(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, Il2CppException**) + 539 (Runtime.cpp:539)
4  GameApp            0x10126bdf0 il2cpp::vm::Runtime::CallUnhandledExceptionDelegate(Il2CppDomain*, Il2CppDelegate*, Il2CppException*) + 476 (Runtime.cpp:476)
5  GameApp            0x10126bd7c il2cpp::vm::Runtime::UnhandledException(Il2CppException*) + 632 (Runtime.cpp:632)
6  GameApp            0x100cb5424 ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool) + 362 (ScriptingInvocation.cpp:362)
7  GameApp            0x100cbcbf0 Coroutine::InvokeMoveNext(ScriptingExceptionPtr*) + 71 (ScriptingInvocation.h:71)
8  GameApp            0x100cbc7c8 Coroutine::Run(bool*) + 257 (Coroutine.cpp:257)
9  GameApp            0x100c09fc0 AsyncOperation::InvokeCoroutine() + 21 (AsyncOperation.cpp:21)
10 GameApp            0x100c26590 PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingSingleStep(PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingFlags, int) + 455 (PreloadManager.cpp:455)
11 GameApp            0x100c26ba4 PreloadManager::UpdatePreloading() + 565 (PreloadManager.cpp:565)
12 GameApp            0x100c1b6a8 ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*) + 347 (PlayerLoop.cpp:347)
13 GameApp            0x100c1b6dc ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*) + 365 (PlayerLoop.cpp:365)
14 GameApp            0x100c1b8bc PlayerLoop() + 45 (RecursionLimit.h:45)
15 GameApp            0x100e71c24 UnityPlayerLoopImpl(bool) + 272 (LibEntryPoint.mm:272)
16 GameApp            0x10052a898 UnityRepaint + 280 (UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:280)
17 GameApp            0x10052a774 -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaintDisplayLink] + 72 (UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:72)
18 QuartzCore         0x240809ff0 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 636
19 IOKit              0x23c6564b0 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 488
20 CoreFoundation     0x23c36519c __CFMachPortPerform + 188
21 CoreFoundation     0x23c38bda0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
22 CoreFoundation     0x23c38b4ec __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 440
23 CoreFoundation     0x23c386310 __CFRunLoopRun + 2096
24 CoreFoundation     0x23c3857c0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
25 GraphicsServices   0x23e58679c GSEventRunModal + 104
26 UIKitCore          0x268a3ec38 UIApplicationMain + 212
27 GameApp            0x100522310 main + 41 (main.mm:41)
28 libdyld.dylib      0x23be498e0 start + 4
```

And some relevant code snippets from UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:

```
64 - (void)repaintDisplayLink
65 {
66 #if ENABLE_DISPLAY_LINK_PAUSING
67     _displayLink.paused = YES;
68 #endif
69     if (!_didResignActive)
70     {
71         [self repaint];
72         [self processTouchEvents];
73     }
74
75 #if ENABLE_DISPLAY_LINK_PAUSING
76     _displayLink.paused = NO;
77 #endif
78 }
```

```
267 extern "C" void UnityRepaint()
268 {
269     @autoreleasepool
270     {
271         // this will handle running on metal just fine (nop)
272         EAGLContextSetCurrentAutoRestore autorestore(GetMainDisplaySurface());
273
274         Profiler_FrameStart();
275
276         UnityInputProcess();
277         UnityPlayerLoop();
278
279         Profiler_FrameEnd();
280     }
281 }
```

I'm at a loss here, do you have any insights on what might be causing this? Any ideas how we should proceed to resolve this crash?

Comment: id want to put some log messages in to see which of those 5 lines is causing it

Comment: @BugFinder As I said in the post we're not able to reproduce this crash ourselves, but have to rely on the stacktraces from our players. I don't think log messages would help much since we can't really see them in the information we get from crashlytics

Comment: Hey, did you ever solve this. I'm experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: @JulienS. I'm sorry, no. To this date we have not made any progress on this

Comment: @EmilOlofsson Thank you for your response. What have you done instead? Or are you just living with the issue for now?